# TSQL: quoted identifiers cast as parameters

Tags: t-sql, parameters

Are quoted identifiers implicitly cast when passed as parameters?

This seems strange because it doesn't work for variables and in a query they are treated completely differently.

```html
CREATE PROC dbo.TestProc 
(
 @param nvarchar(10)
)
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT @param
END

EXEC dbo.TestProc "foo"
EXEC dbo.TestProc 'foo'

SELECT "foo"
SELECT 'foo'
```

```
DECLARE @param NVARCHAR(10) = "foo"
Invalid column name 'foo'.
```

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. You haven't identified the database software.

Comment: wow it even works without the quotes in sql-server-2014 for the `EXEC` call, unless the literal starts with a numeric digit... and it is silently truncated to the 10 nchars given as the param size. bug or not, for sure a selectlist item is not the same kind of token as the value of a parameter in an exec call. the EBNF has never been published in its entirety, but this may help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx vs. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188332(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: this must be a flaw in the TSQL parser. it accepts and casts almost anything to a string here, allowing square brackets, single quotes and double quotes as delimiters, and, most surprising, unquoted literals that match the criteria of an identifier, end up in the string as well. don't see a problem or how this could be exploited, but file a bug.

Comment: It looks like the setting of [`QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx) is "helping". More [here](http://ranjithk.com/2010/01/10/understanding-set-quoted_identifier-onoff/).

Comment: tried it, no change. `EXEC` still accepts single, double, square bracket literals and unquoted tokens that look like identifiers for the nvarchar(10) parameter (tested on a 10.50.1617.0 and an 11.0.6020.0)

Answer (score 0):

Because you defined @param as nvarchar(10) type which only accept value quoted by single quote (by default), so the second command(EXEC dbo.TestProc 'foo') is by default correct. If without using **

> SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON (by default it's OFF)

** Command, TWO single quotes(Not double quotes) is used to escape singe quote, if you would like to make the second exec command works, you have to SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON, which is allow to use double quote to specify character, that means "foo" could be passed to nvarchar(10), and will show foo(no any quotes) in the result window because no matter single quote or double quotes are used to let the sql knows that the which part is the character value you are going to assign to the parameter

Hope it helps xD